# counting the number of dynamically added elements in android

Tags: android

my application includes a button which adds EditText boxes dynamically on every click. What I intend to do is set an ID to each one of the added boxes. I'm doing this using setId() method. But i am unable to reference the newly added boxes. Is it possible to set the id using any loop an then reference by that ID number? My code is as follows:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.time_table);
    l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int i = 0;
            ed = new EditText(Table.this);
            l1.addView(ed);
            ed.setHint("Column Name");
            ed.setId(i);
            i++;
            int n = ed.getId();
            EditText editn = (EditText) findViewById(n);
            editn.setText("new item");
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are declaring you variable `i` inside the `onclick` method so all the edit box would have the ID 0. Declaring your variable `i` as the class variable might fix the issue... Also trying setting ID before adding it to layout...

Answer (score 1):

Just have a count variable:

```
int count = 100;
```

every time you create a View, `setId(count + 1);`

to get the last view `R.id.count`, similarly others.

More elegant soultion would be:

Every time you set the ID, store the id in an ArrayList.